# Removing duplicates from python array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-requests

Write a Python program in which the user can enter a list of values and these
values are then printed in the same order but without duplicates.
Use the sentinel "DONE" to end the input list.

I am failing to make the user to input their own strings,i tried something check my code below.

Sample I/O

```
Enter strings (end with DONE):
the
old
man
and
the
sea
DONE

Sample Output
Unique list:
the
old
man
and
sea
```

My code:

```
a = ["Hello","Huitahani","good","Hello","apple","donkey","zebra","apple"]
a = set(a)
result = [] 
for item in a: 
    if item not in a: 
        a.add(item) 
        result.append(item) 
print(a)
```

Comment: just check if input is already in list, and append it if it's not. (and show more effort for your next question.)

Comment: i'm failing to make the user the user to insert their own inputs

Comment: Use input() to get the input from the user. Check this out if you have never used input() before https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/

Comment: so it should be a = input() ?

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```
a = []
item = input("Enter string (end with DONE):")
while not item == "DONE" : 
    if item not in a: 
        a.append(item)
    item = input("Enter next string (end with DONE):")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few changes to your code:

```
a = ["Hello","Huitahani","good","Hello","apple","donkey","zebra","apple"]
# don't convert to set as it can mess up the order
result = [] 
for item in a: 
    if item not in result: # check if there is already one in result
        result.append(item) 

print(result) # print the new list instead of the original list
```

Output: `['Hello', 'Huitahani', 'good', 'apple', 'donkey', 'zebra']`

If you want to get user input, you could try this:

```
print('Enter strings (end with DONE):')
input_list = []
while True:
    user_input = input()
    if user_input == 'DONE':
        break
    input_list.append(user_input)
```